# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery3510144183145483060441' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I try to use ajax to send date data to php laravel controller.

I tried put _token in data

```
$(document).on("click","#filter",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('get in...')
        $.ajax({
                url:"/report/brewingListReport",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                data: {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    "startDate": startDate,
                    "endDate": endDate
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error : function(e){ 
                    console.log(e.status); 
                }
            })
    
    })
```

this is error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNRbY.png)

I tried to put in header of layout.blade.php

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--DatePicker-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

same error

please help me! I already stuck on here for 2 days!
thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your parent selector?

Comment: are you using skype or teamviewer or your code is hosted online ?